# Illustrator: is possible to layout a looping complex shape overlaping?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

i'm trying to do this shape:

[image: sample1]

So i start to figure out with a simple circle with a corner more distant:

[image: sample2]

and then clone and rotate the same shape:

[image: sample3]

Basically i want to do this without the 3D effect, i just want to give the appearance that one part of the shape overlap the other one ... but it was impossible to me ... is any way that i can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Cut the shape into pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a circle and a tear shape aligned top/center
- Rotate/duplicate the *Tear Shape* 120º from the circle center

[image: Tear]

- Delete the left/bottom paths of each *tear shape*
- Apply **Projecting Cap** from the **Stroke Panel**

[image: Three Tears]

- Select the three shapes and **Expand Stroke**

[image: Expand Stroke]

- Use the **Pen** to delete points outside the figure
- Use the **Shape Builder Tool** pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to delete overlapping paths

[image: Shape Builder Tool]

- Select the three shapes and convert them to a **Symbol**

[image: Symbol]

- Apply **3D Rotate**

[image: 3D rotate]

- Once done you can edit the symbol by double clicking on the figure to add the gradients and shadows

[image: EndII]

Comment: YOu may wish to cut a bit further

Comment: Outch thats some nasty aetifacts you got in the last picture. You know theres a better way to make the base shape.

Comment: Thanks for this incredible explain! But i have a problem, i'm trying to do the tear symbol exaclty like you have but i can't have the same results that you have. For the tear I'm put a circle inside the big circle in the top center and i pull the bottom point in order to have the tear form... but when i rotate the symbol doesn't see like yours...

Comment: Solved the problem. Also, i can't apply the 3D effect, Illustrator gives me an error "THE OPERATION CANNOT COMPLETE BECAUSE OF AN UNKNOW ERROR [CANT]"

Comment: Save the file and restart Illustrator